# Leetcode Two sum problem, why is return[] needed?

Tags: python

This one is problem:

https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/

Given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `target`, return *indices of the two numbers such that they add up to `target`*.
You may assume that each input would have **exactly one solution**, and you may not use the *same* element twice.
You can return the answer in any order.

**I have a question**. the first code- which is not working due to time error- is what I coded and the second one is what I found at the solutions. I found that only difference between them is the existence of `return []` code which I thought useless (Because, once the above return line is executed, then code ends) Can anyone explain me why should I put `return []` line to my code to avoid run time error?

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for ii in range(i+1,len(nums)):
                if target == nums[i] + nums[ii]:
                    return [i,ii]
```

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
                if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                    return [i, j]
        return []
```

Comment: you know that leetcode provides you an answer to this question right? plus it has a discussion page where many people are giving answers to each question

Comment: If your original code is too slow then the second piece of code will also be too slow. The return of an empty list is irrelevant because Leetcode states in the problem description that there **will** be an answer. In case there is no answer (such as if you're providing the input values yourself) then it's up to you what you return. I would favour None

Comment: Your code worked for me... maybe retry! The time complexity of the two is the same and as you recognized the `return []` is useless because the problem states that there will __always__ be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that your algorithm requires number of operations that is in order of  n*n where n is length of input array. (for each index you check against each  index).

You need a more efficient approach. If you input array on n numbers is sorted, you can find 2nd number using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). For each number in input array,  you then require just log(n) operations, to validate if sum exists.
Such algorithm requires n * log(n) operations and that is much less operations when n is large . For example when n is 1e4 that is approx 4e4 vs 1e8 as your approach. That is more than 1000x faster.